# Object Detection with TensorFlow 2 : ImportError: cannot import name 'anchor_generator_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train a model using Tensorflow 2 as written here:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sLqFKVV94wm-lglFq_0kGo2ciM0kecWD#scrollTo=fF8ysCfYKgTP&uniqifier=1

But when I run: python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
This error is returned to me: ImportError: cannot import name 'anchor_generator_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos'

I was looking for answers with such a problem on the internet. Everywhere there are two answers - either "pip install" is missing, or you need to use protoc 3.4. But that doesn't work for me.
i tried versions protoc 3.17 and 3.4, It does not help.
Please tell me how you can solve this problem.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Did you install the dependencies as outlined in your link?

Comment: I did everything that is written.
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/tensorflow/models
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install .

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It turned out that python was trying to import files from a different directory. I moved the project to this folder and it worked.

I spent 2 days solving this problem.
If anyone has the same problem, take a close look at where the import fails.